# How can several rows from a mapping table be rolled up into columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a table structure that can be simplified to this:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Orders (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    UserId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(Id)
);

CREATE TABLE Logos (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE OrderLogos (
    Order_Id INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Orders(Id),
    Logo_Id INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Logos(Id)
);

INSERT INTO Users(Id, Email)
VALUES (1, 'test@email.com');

INSERT INTO Logos(Id, [Name])
VALUES (1, 'First Logo'), (2, 'Second Logo'), (3, 'Third Logo'), (4, 'Fourth Logo');

INSERT INTO Orders(Id, UserId)
VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1);

INSERT INTO OrderLogos(Order_Id, Logo_Id)
VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 3);
```

As you can see, the relationship between `Orders` and `Logos` is many-to-many, with the mapping table being `OrderLogos`.

I now need to write a query that will return 1 row per order with the first 4 logos mapped to it e.g.

```
SELECT
    o.Id AS OrderId,
    u.[Email] AS UserEmail,
    ? AS Logo1,
    ? AS Logo2,
    ? AS Logo3,
    ? AS Logo4
FROM Orders o
JOIN Users u ON o.UserId = u.Id
? - somehow join to Logos while retaining 1 row per order
```

where `Logo1` - `Logo4` would be the `Name` field from the `Logos` table. I've looked into using `PIVOT` and `FOR XML`, but those functions are new to me and I don't quite understand how I could apply either of those in this situation.

Based on the example data above, I would expect the resulting rows to be:

```
1, 'test@email.com', 'First Logo', 'Second Logo', 'Third Logo', 'Fourth Logo'
2, 'test@email.com', 'First Logo', 'Third Logo', NULL, NULL
```

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired output. You mentioned `PIVOT` & `FOR XML`, but both functionally different.

Comment: @YogeshSharma done!

Comment: Hint : `dynamic PIVOT`

Comment: @YogeshSharma Can you please elaborate a bit more or possibly show an example? I'm still failing to see how `PIVOT` can be applied here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use sub queries? If you ever only want the 4 first logos for any order you could use sub queries like below:

```
SELECT
o.Id AS OrderId,
u.[Email] AS UserEmail,
l1.Logo1,
l2.Logo2,
l3.Logo3,
l4.Logo4
FROM Orders o
JOIN Users u ON o.UserId = u.Id
OUTER APPLY (SELECT l.Name AS Logo1 
             FROM OrderLogos ol JOIN #Logos l ON ol.Logo_Id = l.Id 
             WHERE Order_Id = o.id 
             ORDER BY Logo_Id  
             OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) L1

OUTER APPLY (SELECT l.Name AS Logo2 
             FROM OrderLogos ol 
             JOIN Logos l ON ol.Logo_Id = l.Id 
             WHERE Order_Id = o.id 
             ORDER BY Logo_Id  
             OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) L2

OUTER APPLY (SELECT l.Name AS Logo3 
             FROM OrderLogos ol 
             JOIN Logos l ON ol.Logo_Id = l.Id 
             WHERE Order_Id = o.id 
             ORDER BY Logo_Id  
             OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) L3

OUTER APPLY (SELECT l.Name AS Logo4 
             FROM OrderLogos ol 
             JOIN Logos l ON ol.Logo_Id = l.Id 
             WHERE Order_Id = o.id 
             ORDER BY Logo_Id  
             OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) L4
```

Not pretty but think it will work...

Comment: Ah, I did try using sub queries, but in the SELECT portion e.g. `SELECT o.Id, (SELECT TOP 1 l.[Name] FROM OrderLogos ol JOIN Logos l ON ol.Logo_ID = l.Id WHERE ol.Order_ID = o.Id) ...`, but was getting errors about binding the `o` alias inside the sub query. I was unaware of the `OUTER APPLY` operator. I may have to go with this while I look for a prettier solution. Thanks for the `OUTER APPLY` tip!

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simpler query using ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT
    o.Id AS OrderId,
    u.[Email] AS UserEmail,
    MAX(CASE WHEN lg.RowNum=1 THEN lg.Name END) AS Logo1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN lg.RowNum=2 THEN lg.Name END) AS Logo2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN lg.RowNum=3 THEN lg.Name END) AS Logo3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN lg.RowNum=4 THEN lg.Name END) AS Logo4
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Users u ON o.UserId = u.Id
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT  l.Name, ol.Order_Id, ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER (PARTITION BY ol.Order_Id ORDER BY (l.Id)) AS RowNum
    FROM OrderLogos ol
    INNER JOIN Logos l ON ol.Logo_Id=l.Id
    )lg ON o.Id=lg.Order_Id AND RowNum<=4
GROUP BY o.Id, u.Email
```

Comment: Thanks! This does seem simpler; however, my actual query is a bit more complicated with 40+ fields and 10 joins excluding anything to do with the logos, which would make the `GROUP BY` massive.